# Towers of algebras, their 2-step centralizer algebras, and analogues of the degenerate affine Hecke algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, affine-hecke-algebras

Let $\, \big( {\frak{F}}_0 \subset {\frak{F}}_1 \subset {\frak{F}}_2 \subset \cdots \big)$ be a tower of semi-simple, finite dimensional, unital, complex algebras starting with ${\frak{F}}_0 \cong \Bbb{C}$. Let's assume that the *branching rule* of the tower is multiplicity-free, i.e. For any $n \geq 1 $ and any pair of irreducible representations $V$ of $\, {\frak{F}}_n$ and $W$ of $\, {\frak{F}}_{n-1}$ either $W$ occurs with multiplicity one or zero in the restriction $\mathrm{Res}^{\, {\frak{F}}_n}_{\, {\frak{F}}_{n-1}} \! (V)$
of the representation of $V$ to $\, {\frak{F}}_{n-1}$. Let $Z \big( \,{\frak{F}}_n \big)$ denote the center of $\, {\frak{F}_n}$ and
let $Z\big(\, {\frak{F}}_{n-2} \subset \, {\frak{F}}_n \big)$
denote the 2-step centralizer algebra of $\, {\frak{F}}_{n-2}$ inside of $\,{\frak{F}}_n$.

As usual our guiding light in such circumstances is the tower $\, {\frak{F}}_n = \Bbb{C}[S_n]$ of group algebras of the symmetric groups $S_n$. In this case,
there is an algebra homomorphism $\varphi_n$ mapping the *degenerate affine Hecke algebra* $H(2)$ to
each 2-step centralizer algebra $Z\big(\, {\frak{F}}_{n-2} \subset \, {\frak{F}}_n \big)$ where $H(2)$ has a presentation with three generators $Y_1, Y_2, s$ subject to defining relations

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rl}
Y_1 Y_2 &= \, Y_2Y_1 \\
s^2 &= \, 1 \\
sY_2 &= \, Y_1s \, + \, 1
\end{array}
\end{equation}

and where $\varphi_n(Y_2)=\varphi_{n+1}(Y_1) = J_n$
is the $n$-th Jucys-Murphy element in $\Bbb{C}[S_n]$ and $\varphi_n(s) = s_{n-1}$ is the transposition $(n-1, n)$. Moreover
$Z\big(\, {\frak{F}}_{n-2} \subset \, {\frak{F}}_n \big)$ is generated by the
$\mathrm{im} (\varphi_n)$ together with $Z \big( \,{\frak{F}}_{n-2} \big)$.
Of course $H(2)$ is infinite dimensional and so the 2-step centralizer
$Z\big(\, {\frak{F}}_{n-2} \subset \, {\frak{F}}_n \big)$
only sees a shadow of the overall structure of $H(2)$.

**First Question:** Is there some, for lack of a better adjective, *universal* construction which allow us to recover $H(2)$ only using knowledge of the 2-step centralizer algebras  $Z\big(\, {\frak{F}}_{n-2} \subset \, {\frak{F}}_n \big)$ for all $n \geq 2$ ?

For other towers, one can often find  Jucys-Murphy elements
which satisfy a "deformed" version of the $H(2)$-relation $sY_2 = Y_1s + 1$. For example, in the case of the tower of *Brauer* algebras $\, {\frak{F}}_n = \, {\frak{B}}_n(\delta)$ pairs of consecutive Jucys-Murphy elements $J^{\scriptscriptstyle \frak{B}}_n$ and $J^{\scriptscriptstyle \frak{B}}_{n-1}$ satisfy the relation

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cl}
J^{\scriptscriptstyle \frak{B}}_{n-1} J^{\scriptscriptstyle \frak{B}}_{n} &= \,
J^{\scriptscriptstyle \frak{B}}_{n} J^{\scriptscriptstyle \frak{B}}_{n-1} \\
\big( s^{\scriptscriptstyle \frak{B}}_{n-1} \big)^2
&= \, s^{\scriptscriptstyle \frak{B}}_{n-1} \\
s^{\scriptscriptstyle \frak{B}}_{n-1} J^{\scriptscriptstyle \frak{B}}_n &= \,
J^{\scriptscriptstyle \frak{B}}_{n-1} s^{\scriptscriptstyle \frak{B}}_{n-1} \, + \, 1 \, - \, e^{\scriptscriptstyle \frak{B}}_{n-1} 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

where $s^{\scriptscriptstyle \frak{B}}_{1}, \dots, s^{\scriptscriptstyle \frak{B}}_{n-1}$ and $e^{\scriptscriptstyle \frak{B}}_1, \dots,e^{\scriptscriptstyle \frak{B}}_{n-1}$ are the generators of $\, {\frak{B}}_n$ and $\big(e^{\scriptscriptstyle \frak{B}}_k\big)^2 = \delta \, e^{\scriptscriptstyle \frak{B}}_k$. For brevity's sake I'll omit remaining the defining relations.

**Second Question:** Loosely put, and in light of my first question, given a tower of algebras $\big( \, {\frak{F}_n} \big)_{n \geq 0}$ is there some analogue $H^{\scriptscriptstyle {\frak{F}}}(2)$ of the degenerate affine Hecke algebra such that

\begin{equation}
H^{\scriptscriptstyle {\frak{F}}}(2) \cong
\Bbb{C}\big[Y_1, Y_2 \big] \otimes {\frak{F}_2}
\end{equation}

as vector spaces, and such that $H^{\scriptscriptstyle {\frak{F}}}(2)$ is equipped with a family of algebra homomorphisms
\begin{equation}
\varphi_n^{\scriptscriptstyle {\frak{F}}}
: H^{\scriptscriptstyle {\frak{F}}}(2)
\longrightarrow 
Z\big(\, {\frak{F}}_{n-2} \subset \, {\frak{F}}_n \big)
\end{equation}

where $\varphi_n(Y_2)= \varphi_{n+1}(Y_1)$ is the $n$-th Jucys-Murphy element inside ${\frak{F}}_{n}$ and such that
$Z\big(\, {\frak{F}}_{n-2} \subset \, {\frak{F}}_n \big)$ is generated by
$\mathrm{im} (\varphi^{\scriptscriptstyle {\frak{F}}}_n)$ and $Z \big( \,{\frak{F}}_{n-2} \big)$ for all $n \geq 2$ ?

thanks, ines.